# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query :

```
CASE
   WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(dbo.Post.OdaSayisi, 1, CHARINDEX('+', dbo.Post.OdaSayisi) - 1)) = 1 
      THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Post.OdaSayisi, 1, CHARINDEX('+', dbo.Post.OdaSayisi) - 1)
      ELSE 0
END AS RoomNumber,
```

where `OdaSayisi` is a string like 3+1, 4+2. When I try to write this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[MyView] 
WHERE RoomNumber = 3
```

I get this error in the title. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you have rows which are either `NULL` or do not contain the `+` symbol.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu So, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that some values of `OdaSayisi` do not have a `'+'` in them.  The simplest solution is to put one in for the `CHARINDEX()` functions

```
(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(dbo.Post.OdaSayisi, 1, CHARINDEX('+', dbo.Post.OdaSayisi + '+') - 1)) = 1
      THEN SUBSTRING(dbo.Post.OdaSayisi, 1, CHARINDEX('+', dbo.Post.OdaSayisi + '+') - 1)
      ELSE 0
 END) AS RoomNumber,
```

The `+ '+'` ensures that `CHARINDEX()` will not return a negative number.

Comment: `+ '+'` This will return NULL when the column contains NULL. (Server settings apply). So this won't help in that case.

Comment: @Pred . . . If any of the arguments are `NULL`, the `substring()` returns `NULL`.  The problem is a negative length argument cause by `CHARINDEX()` not finding the character.

Answer (score 1):

**CHARINDEX**

> If either expressionToFind or expressionToSearch is NULL, CHARINDEX returns NULL.
>   If expressionToFind is not found within expressionToSearch, CHARINDEX returns 0.

**SUBSTRING**

> The numbering is 1 based, meaning that the first character in the expression is 1

Answer (score 0):

You need first to test if the field [dbo.Post.OdaSayisi] is not empty, and then evaluate existence of '+' in your fields.

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(dbo.Post.OdaSayisi, '!Zz!') <> '!Zz!'
THEN
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('+', dbo.Post.OdaSayisi), 1) > 0
    THEN
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(dbo.Post.OdaSayisi, 1, CHARINDEX('+', dbo.Post.OdaSayisi) - 1)) = 1 
        THEN 
           SUBSTRING(dbo.Post.OdaSayisi, 1, CHARINDEX('+', dbo.Post.OdaSayisi) - 1)
    ELSE 0
        END
    ELSE 0
    END
ELSE 0
END AS RoomNumber,
```

Hope this can help.