# SQL Server RIGHT function returns an error with no null or empty values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Following SQL Server function works fine with simple examples but when it is passed a column that has millions of records, it gives the error shown below:

**Question**: What could be a cause of the problem, and it can be fixed?

**Function**:

```
Create FUNCTION MyFunction(@var varchar(300))
RETURNS varchar(300)
AS
BEGIN

    IF LEN(ISNULL(@var, '')) = 0
        return @var

    declare @varLen tinyint = LEN(@var)

    SET @var = CASE
    WHEN LEFT(@var,4) = 'abc ' THEN RIGHT(@var,@varLen-4)
    WHEN LEFT(@var,4) = 'abc.' THEN RIGHT(@var,@varLen-4)
    WHEN LEFT(@var,3) = 'rs ' THEN RIGHT(@var,@varLen-3)
    WHEN LEFT(@var,4) = 'rs. ' THEN RIGHT(@var,@varLen-4)
    ELSE @var
    END

    RETURN @var
END
```

**Simple query** [correctly returns the expected output]:

```
declare @t varchar(150) = 'abc ewotiu ryire'
select dbo.TestFunction(@t)  --returns "ewotiu ryire"
```

**Sample Query that gives an error**:

```
select myColumn MyFunction(myColumn) from myTable
```

**REMARKS**:

1. myColumn has millions of records, has no null values, there are about 10 empty values (blanks `''`). But I have taken care of that scenario in the first line of the code above. I have tested that when I pass null or blank string, it correctly returns null or empty string.
2. I have also tried using `DATALENGTH` function instead of `LEN`, but still the exact same error
3. Using Azure SQL Db: `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Sep 18 2021 19:01:34   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation`
4. Online search (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39320384/1232087) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40589907/1232087) etc.) did not help - probably my issue is a bit different having to do with millions of records or something else.

**Error**: [When passed to a query with million of records ]

> > Msg 536, Level 16, State 2
> > Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: Or inlining might be the problem.  What version of SQL Server?  IE add the output of `select @@version` to the question.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Just added it in item 3 of **Remarks** section.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft But my `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;` query shows the compatibility level to be `150` that is for SQL Server 2019. [Ref.](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/01/sql-performance/compatibility-levels-and-cardinality-estimation-primer). Correct?

Comment: My mistake.  I missed that it was Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 1):

You will see this error if you pass `'abc '` or `'rs '` to your function as `LEN` does not count trailing spaces.

So for `'rs '` the expression `RIGHT(@var,@varLen-3)` ends up as `RIGHT('rs ',2-3)` and `-1` is an invalid length.

You can use the following instead to just specify the desired start position directly instead of calculating it with `LEN`

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION MyFunction(@var VARCHAR(300))
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN CASE WHEN @var LIKE 'abc %' OR @var LIKE 'abc.%' OR @var LIKE 'rs. %' THEN SUBSTRING(@var, 5, 300)
               WHEN @var LIKE 'rs %' THEN SUBSTRING(@var, 4, 300)
               ELSE @var
             END
  END
```

The reason for switching to `LIKE` is so that trailing spaces also become significant in the string comparison part. Otherwise `'rs'` and `'rs '` will also compare equal (which would also give the error in your original function and needs to be guarded against to give the desired results in the rewrite).

Comment: If I change `LEN` to `DATALENGTH`, `select dbo.TestFunction('abc ')` simply returns empty string with no error. But as I stated in my Remark 2, using `DATALENGTH` also gives the exact same error on `select myColumn MyFunction(myColumn) from myTable`.

Comment: You have two instances of LEN in your function which did you change? But either way you still have the issue I mention at the end with passing `'rs'` (with no trailing space). This is only 2 characters either way and goes through to the `RIGHT(@var,@varLen-3)` branch

Comment: I changed both instances of `LEN` to `DATALENGTH`.

Comment: So the second issue mentioned then https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98cecac2fb9b7e44457e00306096d81c

Answer (score 0):

to illustrate your problem:

```
declare @a varchar(300)
set @a = 'abc'
if LEFT(@a,4) = 'abc '
  select LEN(@a)-4

-----------
-1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

To illustrate one more problem in your code

```
declare @a varchar(300)
set @a = REPLICATE('A',300)

declare @varLen tinyint = LEN(@a)

Msg 220, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint, value = 300.
```